# Page associated with a "like" button on external site isn't in list of Facebook Pages in FB

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, external

I have a like button on a blog post here - http://blog.thinkplanrun.com/2012/03/2012-tpr-shoe-madness/ - right now it shows 17 "likes".  I am unable to see the FB community page associated with this URL when logged into my FB account.  I currently see quite a few other community pages from external URL "likes" and my official FB Fan Page, but not for this specific article.  Using the debugging tool (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) for this URL it has my admin account listed under admin ... what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

That blog post is not a page, it is a link.

Instead of trying to view the url in the debug tool, try the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=http://blog.thinkplanrun.com/2012/03/2012-tpr-shoe-madness/) with the url.
As you can see, it has "link_stat" as the type.
On the other hand, if you use the same tool for [your page](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=thinkplanrun) you'll see that the type is "page".

Why do you want it to be a page?